# How to confirm no whitespace or trailing data with scanf/sscanf?

Tags: c, whitespace, scanf

sscanf() seems well suited to strip out matching data eg.:

```
sscanf ("abc,f,123,234", "%[a-z],%c,%d,%d", str, &chr, &i1, &i2)
```

However I need to assert that it encountered no whitespace:

```
sscanf ("abc,  f  , 123    , 234  ", "%[a-z],%c,%d,%d", str, &chr, &i1, &i2)
/* How to tell it to fail on whitespace?? */
```

Also I need to assert there is no trailing data:

```
sscanf ("abc,f,123,234__SOMERUBBISH", "%[a-z],%c,%d,%d", str, &chr, &i1, &i2)
/* How to detect trailing rubbish or make sscanf fail */
```

How can I get sscanf to parse the string more strictly?

This is a university assignment compiling as ANSI C and I do not have the option of including regex.

Comment: Fasinating that we have two contradictory answers from very very experienced answerers.  I look forwards to the resolution!

Comment: @GreenAsJade: 'tis curious you consider two identical answers as "contradictory". I have revised my first statement to clarify the meaning of 'et al' (it is the other direct file I/O functions, not sscanf() and the string scanning functions), but the operational format string is the same, byte for byte. I don't regard it as simple; apparently chux does. Each to their own on that. We're 100% in agreement that it can be done, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succinctly, if you cannot allow white space, you cannot use the direct file I/O functions such as `scanf()` et al.  Each of the `%d` conversions allows an arbitrary amount of white space before the value, including newlines.  You must use the string-based functions such as `sscanf()` instead.

You will do best using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the line of data, and then use `%n` to identify where the conversions finish.

If you've not eliminated the newline saved by `fgets()` or `getline()`, you can then test that the first character after the last match (or first unmatched character) in the input is a newline; otherwise, you can test for a null byte as the first unmatched character.

You still need to check that there was no space before either number; you use `%n` again for each of those.  Note that the `%n` conversion specifications are not counted in the number returned by `scanf()` et al.

#### `ws.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char   str[10] = "QQQQQQQQQ";
    char   chr = 'Z';
    int    i1 = 77;
    int    i2 = 88;
    int    n1;
    int    n2;
    int    n3;
    char  *line = 0;
    size_t linelen = 0;
    int    length;

    while ((length = getline(&line, &linelen, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        printf("Line: <<%.*s>>\n", length - 1, line);

        int rc = sscanf(line, "%[a-z],%c,%n%d,%n%d%n",
                        str, &chr, &n1, &i1, &n2, &i2, &n3);

        const char *tag = "success";
        if (rc <= 0)
            tag = "total failure";
        else if (rc < 4)
            tag = "partial failure";
        else if (rc > 4)
            tag = "WTF?";
        printf("rc = %d: %s\n", rc, tag);
        printf("n1 = %d [%c], n2 = %d [%c], n3 = %d [%c]\n",
               n1, line[n1], n2, line[n2], n3, line[n3]);
        printf("<<%s>>,<<%c>>,%d,%d\n", str, chr, i1, i2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This would allow you to identify where there's a problem.

#### `data`

Using ☐ to mark the end of lines, consider the data file (`data`):

```
abc,f,123,234☐
abc,  f  , 123    , 234  ☐
abc,f,123,234__SOMERUBBISH☐
xyz,f, 123, 234☐
xyz,f,123 ,234 ☐
```

#### Example run

The output from the program above is:

```
$ ./ws < data
Line: <<abc,f,123,234>>
rc = 4: success
n1 = 6 [1], n2 = 10 [2], n3 = 13 [
]
<<abc>>,<<f>>,123,234
Line: <<abc,  f  , 123    , 234  >>
rc = 2: partial failure
n1 = 6 [f], n2 = 10 [ ], n3 = 13 [3]
<<abc>>,<< >>,123,234
Line: <<abc,f,123,234__SOMERUBBISH>>
rc = 4: success
n1 = 6 [1], n2 = 10 [2], n3 = 13 [_]
<<abc>>,<<f>>,123,234
Line: <<xyz,f, 123, 234>>
rc = 4: success
n1 = 6 [ ], n2 = 11 [ ], n3 = 15 [
]
<<xyz>>,<<f>>,123,234
Line: <<xyz,f,123 ,234 >>
rc = 3: partial failure
n1 = 6 [1], n2 = 11 [2], n3 = 15 [
]
<<xyz>>,<<f>>,123,234
$
```

Clearly, for the lines marked 'partial failure', you can't rely on the data beyond the last successful conversion.  But where the conversions were successful, you can see that the problems could be discovered by inspecting `line[n1]` etc.

---

#### `ws2.c`

This minor variation of the code gives a slightly extended analysis of the problems.  Note that this analysis does not adapt to partially or wholly unsuccessful scans.  It would be best if it simply reported a problem when the return value from `sscanf()` is not 4, only analyzing the values when the scan was successful.  (The modification to do so is not complicated.) It also prevents buffer overflow for long strings as the first field.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#undef isdecint
static inline int isdecint(int c)
{
    return (isdigit(c) || c == '+' || c == '-');
}

int main(void)
{
    char   str[10] = "QQQQQQQQQ";
    char   chr = 'Z';
    int    i1 = 77;
    int    i2 = 88;
    int    n1;
    int    n2;
    int    n3;
    char  *line = 0;
    size_t linelen = 0;
    int    length;

    while ((length = getline(&line, &linelen, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        printf("Line: <<%.*s>>\n", length - 1, line);

        int rc = sscanf(line, "%9[a-z],%c,%n%d,%n%d%n",
                        str, &chr, &n1, &i1, &n2, &i2, &n3);

        const char *tag = "success";
        if (rc <= 0)
            tag = "total failure";
        else if (rc < 4)
            tag = "partial failure";
        else if (rc > 4)
            tag = "WTF?";
        printf("rc = %d: %s\n", rc, tag);
        printf("n1 = %d [%c], n2 = %d [%c], n3 = %d [%c]\n",
               n1, line[n1], n2, line[n2], n3, line[n3]);
        if (!isdecint(line[n1]))
            printf("Invalid char for n1\n");
        if (!isdecint(line[n2]))
            printf("Invalid char for n2\n");
        if (line[n3] != '\n')
            printf("Invalid char for n3\n");
        printf("<<%s>>,<<%c>>,%d,%d\n", str, chr, i1, i2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### `data2`

```
abc,f,123,234☐
abc,  f  , 345    , 456  ☐
abc,f,567,678__SOMERUBBISH☐
xyz,f, 1234, 2345☐
xyz,f,-3456 ,-4567 ☐
xyz,f,+5678,+6789☐
xyz,f,+ 5678,- 6789 X☐
```

#### Sample run

```
$ ./ws2 < data2
Line: <<abc,f,123,234>>
rc = 4: success
n1 = 6 [1], n2 = 10 [2], n3 = 13 [
]
<<abc>>,<<f>>,123,234
Line: <<abc,  f  , 345    , 456  >>
rc = 2: partial failure
n1 = 6 [f], n2 = 10 [ ], n3 = 13 [5]
Invalid char for n1
Invalid char for n2
Invalid char for n3
<<abc>>,<< >>,123,234
Line: <<abc,f,567,678__SOMERUBBISH>>
rc = 4: success
n1 = 6 [5], n2 = 10 [6], n3 = 13 [_]
Invalid char for n3
<<abc>>,<<f>>,567,678
Line: <<xyz,f, 1234, 2345>>
rc = 4: success
n1 = 6 [ ], n2 = 12 [ ], n3 = 17 [
]
Invalid char for n1
Invalid char for n2
<<xyz>>,<<f>>,1234,2345
Line: <<xyz,f,-3456 ,-4567 >>
rc = 3: partial failure
n1 = 6 [-], n2 = 12 [,], n3 = 17 [7]
Invalid char for n2
Invalid char for n3
<<xyz>>,<<f>>,-3456,2345
Line: <<xyz,f,+5678,+6789>>
rc = 4: success
n1 = 6 [+], n2 = 12 [+], n3 = 17 [
]
<<xyz>>,<<f>>,5678,6789
Line: <<xyz,f,+ 5678,- 6789 X>>
rc = 2: partial failure
n1 = 6 [+], n2 = 12 [,], n3 = 17 [8]
Invalid char for n2
Invalid char for n3
<<xyz>>,<<f>>,5678,6789
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy as pie.

Change format to locate potential undesired white-space.  Use `"%n"` to record scan position in buffer.  Precede format specifiers like `"%d"`, `"%s"`, `"%f"` that consume optional leading white-space.  Add a final `"%n"` to check for trailing garbage.

First check that 4 variable were scanned.  Then check if undesired data occurred.

Note: , Only `"%[]"`, `"%c"`, `"%n"` do not consume optional leading white-space.

```
int ws[3];
int cnt = sscanf (buf, "%[a-z],%c,%n%d,%n%d%n", str, &chr, &ws[0], &i1, &ws[1], &i2, &ws[2]);
if (cnt != 4 || isspace(buf[ws[0]]) || isspace(buf[ws[1]]) || buf[ws[2]]) {
    Fail();
}
```

Comment: "%s" will immediate stop if leading white space encountered.

Comment: @user3629249 `"%s"` will _not_ immediate stop if leading white space encountered.   These white-spaces are skipped.  "Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier." C11dr §7.21.6.2 8

Comment: here is an excerpt from the man page: 's      Matches  a  sequence  of  non-white-space  characters;  the next
              pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough
              to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'),
              which is added automatically.  **The input string stops  at  white
              space** or at the maximum field width, **whichever occurs first.**
'   emphasis mine

Comment: @user3629249 Check your man page for "Most conversions discard initial white space characters".  P.S.  C spec beats man page.

Comment: @user3629249  Try `char s[9] = "n"; sscanf(" y", "%s", s); puts(s);`

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for sscanf:

> [
>
> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of
>   accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and
>   there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a
>   terminating null byte. The usual skip of leading white space is
>   suppressed. The string is to be made up of characters in (or not in) a
>   particular set; the set is defined by the characters between the open
>   bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character. The set excludes
>   those characters if the first character after the open bracket is a
>   circumflex (^). To include a close bracket in the set, make it the
>   first character after the open bracket or the circumflex; any other
>   position will end the set. The hyphen character - is also special;
>   when placed between two other characters, it adds all intervening
>   characters to the set. To include a hyphen, make it the last character
>   before the final close bracket. For instance, [^]0-9-] means the set
>   "everything except close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen". The
>   string ends with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a
>   circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

This should give you finer control over your inputs. (But it is basically a poor version of regex.)

Comment: Skylor, welcome. No downvote, but just a helpful tip. Generally posting sections of man pages for answers is discouraged. While a brief quote as part of a larger answer is fine, a large quote as part of a brief answer is generally not. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I have gotten 'my hand slapped' for only referencing a man page and not posting the relevant portion of the text in the man page.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the fields into strings first, check whether the strings start or end in whitespace, and proceed based on that.

Here's an example program that demonstrates the detection logic.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int startsOrEndsWithSpace(char str[]) 
{
   return (isspace(str[0]) || isspace(str[strlen(str)-2])); 
}

void testSccanf(char const source[],
                char str1[],
                char str2[],
                char str3[],
                char str4[])
{
   int n = sscanf(source, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", str1, str2, str3, str4);
   if ( n != 4 )
   {
      // Problem
      printf("Found only %d fields.\n", n);
   }

   if ( n >= 1 && startsOrEndsWithSpace(str1) )
   {
      printf("1st field is not good\n");
   }

   if ( n >= 2 && startsOrEndsWithSpace(str2) )
   {
      printf("2nd field is not good\n");
   }

   if ( n >=3 && startsOrEndsWithSpace(str3) )
   {
      printf("3rd field is not good\n");
   }

   if ( startsOrEndsWithSpace(str4) )
   {
      printf("4th field is not good\n");
   }
}

int main ()
{
   char str1[50];
   char str2[50];
   char str3[50];
   char str4[50];

   testSccanf("abc,  f  , 123    , 234  ", str1, str2, str3, str4);
   testSccanf("abc,f,123,234", str1, str2, str3, str4);

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Do not use `"stdio.h"` notation instead of `<stdio.h>` for standard headers. It works, but it is very unorthodox.  Also, you can't possibly tell what's good and what's bad without testing the return value from `sscanf()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use getchar() to see if the next character is a newline character or spaces.

Comment: I guess that helps with trailing newline, but not spaces?